# How are [links][1] supposed to appear, or is it broken?

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks, markdown-rendering

How should a link created [like this][1] be displayed?  It doesn't do what I expect, but thinking about it, I'm not sure if I expect a link to the 'link' or a link to the footnote, *wikimedia* style.  It does neither.

[I'm using Google Chrome][1]
Here's a link using an [actual URL](http://www.stackexchange.com)

Here is another attempt to [link](http://www.example.com).  Well that kinda worked, but it isn't referenced as a footnote like the numerical one. It looked like this:

```
[link][examplesite]
...
[examplesite]: http://www.example.com
```

This is what the help panel says currently (June 2015):

> To create fancier links, use Markdown:
>
> > Here's [a link](http://www.example.com/)! And a reference-style link to [a panda][1].
> >
> > References don't have to be [numbers][question].
> >
> > [1]: http://notfound.stackexchange.com/
> >     [question]: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11481

Nothing happens in the help pane either, is it supposed to?

- Is this broken?
- Does the help pane need updating?

[1]: Version 43.0.2357.81 m on Windows 7 64

Comment: `[1]: Version 43.0.2357.81 m on Windows 7 64`  <-- That's not a URL

Comment: So?  That's my point, is it required? What is the end-to-end objective here?  I agree it's not a URL, so, what behavior is that causing?

Comment: Are you saying you're expecting something that's _not_ a URL to work as a link? What about the help page makes you think that your "Version 43.0.2357.81 m on Windows 7 64" should display as anything but text in the question?

Comment: I often feel sad for our people who, for a while, put all their efforts in a help center nobody reads.

Comment: It is required for those to be a link -- they're not footnotes (although they appear like them in syntax).  The reason why the ones you quoted don't work right there is because it doesn't accept the `> ` blockquote before the link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key misunderstanding here is that the syntax you are playing with is not for creating footnotes which show up in the final rendered text, it's just a way of keeping URLs out of the way while writing a post, and of reusing them multiple times.

So the idea is to replace this:

```
Some text with [a link](http://somelongdomain.example.com/lengthy-url-path/) in it.
```

With this:

```
Some text with [a link][1] in it.

[1]: http://somelongdomain.example.com/lengthy-url-path/
```

And **produce exactly the same output**.

The link is still in its place in context for the reader, but it doesn't get in your way when editing and proofreading your Markdown source.

I think the idea comes from a practice used in plain text e-mails, newsgroups, forums, etc, where everyone is actually viewing the "source code" (i.e. plain text). You want people to be able to read through the text without being "tripped up" when they come to a URL in the middle of it, so you push the URL down to the bottom as a footnote.

Comment: Only answer to actually address the question "How should it be displayed", meaning, "what is it supposed to look like because I'm doing it wrong and getting confused".  And with minimal flame. Thx!

Answer (score 6):

Linking is described in the help center section on [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

---

```
Here's an inline link to [Google](http://www.google.com/). Here's a
reference-style link to [Google][1]. Here's a very readable link to
[Yahoo!][yahoo].

  [1]: http://www.google.com/   
  [yahoo]: http://www.yahoo.com/
```

The link definitions can appear anywhere in the document -- before or after the place where you use them. The link definition names `[1]` and `[yahoo]` can be any unique string, and are case-insensitive; `[yahoo]` is the same as `[YAHOO]`.

#### Advanced Links

Links can have a title attribute, which will show up on hover. Title attributes can also be added; they are helpful if the link itself is not descriptive enough to tell users where they're going.

```
Here's a [poorly-named link](http://www.google.com/ "Google").
Never write "[click here][^2]".
Visit [us][web].

  [^2]: http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere
        (Advice against the phrase "click here")
  [web]: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ "Programmers Stack Exchange"
```

You can also use standard HTML hyperlink syntax.

```
<a href="http://example.com" title="example">example</a>
```

---

Answer (score -3):

You're doing it wrong!

I had trouble using this method in another post, which is what prompted the question.

The syntax is **VERY** important for this, which is to be expected, but keep in mind the following or you will break it:

- Don't forget the `:` after the link reference, i.e.: `[1]: www.mylink.com`
- You cannot put **ANY** text except the URL in the link area.  This makes it problematic to conform to the advice on [writing good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) which suggests:

  > Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there.

So if you want to add context, make sure the context is added around the link in the post, not around the "footnoted" link.  Or use the title attribute (hover over) functionality mentioned in Advanced Links, which will provide this context.

Comment: Ok, I give up.  I actually agree with the down votes on the question, not 'proud' of it by any means, but understand now.  So, I put an answer addressing the exact points that tripped me up.  If anything, it is not helpful, but I'm sure it is not counter-productive or bad.  Indeed my question should have been posed in chat maybe, to get help with a feature, not as a question, and I considered improving this answer further.  I endured the flame for awhile, but now I just don't care.  So, please, bury it, so that even in the remote possibility my comments are helpful, they won't be seen.